# Explain the other part of the sentence

Tags: grammar

What I had forgotten was that I had a test today

I know that ‘What I had forgotten’ is a noun clause that is acting as the subject but what about the rest of the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

> *What I had forgotten was that I had a test today.*

"What I had forgotten" is not a clause but an NP (noun phrase) in a 'fused' relative construction where the meaning is "the thing that I had forgotten".

The NP is the subject and the verb phrase "was that I had a test today" is the predicate.

The *that* clause is complement of "be" in its specifying sense.

Comment: In this place https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-10/clauses/lesson-5/noun-clauses it says it’s a noun clause.

Comment: @somerandomgirl Ignore what it says. It is wrong.

Comment: Wait so everything in that place is wrong? Or only that part?

Comment: I've no idea what it says. But "what I had forgotten" is definitely a noun phrase, where "what" means "the thing which".

Comment: What would be considered a noun clause then?

Comment: There's no such thing as a 'noun clause', it's just childish nonsense. The classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal structure, not on some spurious analogies with the parts of speech. But that's going off-topic. You can be certain that "what I had forgotten" is an NP.

Comment: I’m sorry and thank you